# how to make my button appear if a condition is meet

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I'm trying to do: Create a function that automatically checks if the Grand Total value is more than 250 and if true more than 250, it will display a button and if the total is not 250 than it wonder appear

so I'm kind of confused on what I'm doing wrong here

```js
function calculateTotal() {

  // first row //
  var Unit_Price_1 = document.getElementById('Unit Price_1').value;
  var Quantity_1 = document.getElementById('Quantity_1').value;
  var Total_1 = document.getElementById('Total_1')
  var Total_Amount_1 = Unit_Price_1 * Quantity_1;
  Total_1.value = Total_Amount_1

  // Second row //
  var Unit_Price_2 = document.getElementById('Unit Price_2').value;
  var Quantity_2 = document.getElementById('Quantity_2').value;
  var Total_2 = document.getElementById('Total_2')
  var Total_Amount_2 = Unit_Price_2 * Quantity_2;
  Total_2.value = Total_Amount_2

  // grand total //
  var arr = document.getElementsByName('total');
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (parseInt(arr[i].value))
      total += parseInt(arr[i].value);

    if (total < 0) {
      alert("an error has occured");
      total = 0
    }

  }
  document.getElementById('total_final').value = total.toFixed(2);

  function DiscountButton() {
    var Amount = document.getElementsByName('total_final');

    if (Amount >= 250) {
      document.getElementById("dis_Button").style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("dis_Button").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table>

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Unit Price</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <!---------------- ROW 1 ------------------>

    <td>
      <input type="number" name="unit price" placeholder="0.00" id="Unit Price_1">
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="number" name="Quality" placeholder="0" id="Quantity_1">
    </td>

    <td>
      <input required type="number" name="total" value="0.00" readonly="readonly" id="Total_1" />
    </td>
    </tr>

    <!---------------- ROW 2 ------------------>

    <td>
      <input type="number" name="unit price" placeholder="0.00" id="Unit Price_2">
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="number" name="Quality" placeholder="0" id="Quantity_2">
    </td>

    <td>
      <input required type="number" name="total" value="0.00" readonly="readonly" id="Total_2" />
    </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input required type="button" value="Calculate Grand Total Price" onclick="calculateTotal();" />
      </td>

      <td colspan="2">
        <input type="number" name="total_final" id="total_final" value="0.00" style="font-size: 18px; background-color: silver" readonly="readonly" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
<button id="dis_Button">Press to apply discount</button>
```

Comment: `var Amount = document.getElementsByName('total_final');` => You should then test Amount.value, not Amount

Answer (score 0):

`Amount` is an element, to get it's value, use `Amount.value`.

```html
    <script>
  function calculateTotal() {
  
  // first row //
  var Unit_Price_1 = document.getElementById('Unit Price_1').value; 
  var Quantity_1 = document.getElementById('Quantity_1').value;
  var Total_1 = document.getElementById('Total_1')
  var Total_Amount_1 = Unit_Price_1 * Quantity_1;
  Total_1.value = Total_Amount_1

  // Second row //
  var Unit_Price_2 = document.getElementById('Unit Price_2').value; 
  var Quantity_2 = document.getElementById('Quantity_2').value;
  var Total_2 = document.getElementById('Total_2')
  var Total_Amount_2 = Unit_Price_2 * Quantity_2;
  Total_2.value = Total_Amount_2

 // grand total //
  var arr = document.getElementsByName('total');
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
     total += parseInt(arr[i].value);

     if(total<0){
      alert("an error has occured");
      total = 0
            }
        
  }
  document.getElementById('total_final').value = total.toFixed(2);

  function DiscountButton(){
  var Amount = +document.getElementsByName('total_final').value;

  if (Amount >= 250){
    document.getElementById("dis_Button").style.visibility = "visible";
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("dis_Button").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }

} }

</script>
```

Comment: but i have added .value at the end and my code but still the button is still visible from the able as i want it to be visible only when the amount is more than 250 ?

Comment: try using a `+` as I did in the example above (but forgot to note down xD). it will make sure that it is a number and not a string

Comment: also, where are you calling DiscountButton?

Answer (score 0):

I found some issues.

The first issue is not call to DiscountButton() function.

The second issue is use wrong method and don't use the property value, the right way is like that.

`var Amount = parseInt(document.getElementById('total_final').value);`

```js
function calculateTotal() {
  
  // first row //
  var Unit_Price_1 = document.getElementById('Unit Price_1').value; 
  var Quantity_1 = document.getElementById('Quantity_1').value;
  var Total_1 = document.getElementById('Total_1')
  var Total_Amount_1 = Unit_Price_1 * Quantity_1;
  Total_1.value = Total_Amount_1

  // Second row //
  var Unit_Price_2 = document.getElementById('Unit Price_2').value; 
  var Quantity_2 = document.getElementById('Quantity_2').value;
  var Total_2 = document.getElementById('Total_2')
  var Total_Amount_2 = Unit_Price_2 * Quantity_2;
  Total_2.value = Total_Amount_2

 // grand total //
  var arr = document.getElementsByName('total');
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
     total += parseInt(arr[i].value);

     if(total<0){
      alert("an error has occured");
      total = 0
            }
        
  }
  
  //console.log(total);
  document.getElementById('total_final').value = total.toFixed(2);
  DiscountButton();
  }

 function DiscountButton(){
 
  var Amount = parseInt(document.getElementById('total_final').value);
  //console.log(Amount);
  if (Amount >= 250){
    document.getElementById("dis_Button").style.visibility = "visible";
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("dis_Button").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}
```

```html
<body>

<table>

<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Unit Price</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Total</th>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
  <!---------------- ROW 1 ------------------>

    <td>
      <input type="number" name="unit price" placeholder="0.00" id="Unit Price_1" >
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="number" name="Quality" placeholder="0" id="Quantity_1" >
    </td>

    <td>
      <input
        required
        type="number"
        name="total"
        value="0.00"
        readonly="readonly"
        id="Total_1"
      />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <!---------------- ROW 2 ------------------>

    <td>
      <input type="number" name="unit price" placeholder="0.00" id="Unit Price_2">
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="number" name="Quality" placeholder="0" id="Quantity_2">
    </td>

    <td>
      <input
        required
        type="number"
        name="total"
        value="0.00"
        readonly="readonly"
        id="Total_2"
      />
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>

<tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input
          required
          type="button" 
          value="Calculate Grand Total Price" 
          onclick="calculateTotal();"
        />
      </td>

        <td colspan="2">
          <input
            type="number"
            name="total_final"
            id="total_final"
            value="0.00"
            style="font-size: 18px; background-color: silver"
            readonly="readonly"
          />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
  <button  id="dis_Button">Press to apply discount</button>
</body>
```

Comment: i have a question, i think i didn't specify. so i want it to automates and that's why i created a new function. as the original grand total input value is started 0 so without press that button (calculate grand total price) it should automates be no button since the orginal input is 0

Answer (score 0):

There is not really the need for the second function `DiscountButton()`. That is why I simply remoced it and added an approriate line to the  `calculateTotal()` function instead:

```js
function calculateTotal() {

  // first row //
  var Unit_Price_1 = document.getElementById('Unit Price_1').value;
  var Quantity_1 = document.getElementById('Quantity_1').value;
  var Total_1 = document.getElementById('Total_1')
  var Total_Amount_1 = Unit_Price_1 * Quantity_1;
  Total_1.value = Total_Amount_1

  // Second row //
  var Unit_Price_2 = document.getElementById('Unit Price_2').value;
  var Quantity_2 = document.getElementById('Quantity_2').value;
  var Total_2 = document.getElementById('Total_2')
  var Total_Amount_2 = Unit_Price_2 * Quantity_2;
  Total_2.value = Total_Amount_2

  // grand total //
  var arr = document.getElementsByName('total');
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (parseInt(arr[i].value))
      total += parseInt(arr[i].value);

    if (total < 0) {
      alert("an error has occured");
      total = 0
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('total_final').value = total.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("dis_Button").style.visibility = total>250 ? "visible":"hidden";
}
```

```html
<table>

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Unit Price</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <!---------------- ROW 1 ------------------>

    <td>
      <input type="number" name="unit price" placeholder="0.00" id="Unit Price_1">
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="number" name="Quality" placeholder="0" id="Quantity_1">
    </td>

    <td>
      <input required type="number" name="total" value="0.00" readonly="readonly" id="Total_1" />
    </td>
    </tr>

    <!---------------- ROW 2 ------------------>

    <td>
      <input type="number" name="unit price" placeholder="0.00" id="Unit Price_2">
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="number" name="Quality" placeholder="0" id="Quantity_2">
    </td>

    <td>
      <input required type="number" name="total" value="0.00" readonly="readonly" id="Total_2" />
    </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input required type="button" value="Calculate Grand Total Price" onclick="calculateTotal();" />
      </td>

      <td colspan="2">
        <input type="number" name="total_final" id="total_final" value="0.00" style="font-size: 18px; background-color: silver" readonly="readonly" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
<button id="dis_Button">Press to apply discount</button>
```

Comment: the reason  why i created a second function is so that its able to automates check for the value before the grand total button is press, so the original value i have assign is 0 so the button shouldn't be there since its less than 250 ( sorry for not making it clear )